# how to fire javascript at the end of DOM and putting in head

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I am loading a javascript at the end of the page just before the endtag body like below:

```
<script src="/plugins/Headroom/js/headroom2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
(function() {
// code js goes here
}());
```

How can I achieve the same result when loading the javascript into the **head** tag?
I already tried to add the ready handler like below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 // code goes here
}());
```

and load this js into the head but without the same result

Comment: you should get en error in a console Use $( document ).ready(function() {
 // code goes here
});

Comment: Remove the () at the end because it executes the function right away.

Comment: Oh yeah, both should give error, otherwise they are equal. You can do `$(function(){ //code });` too. (Remove `()` at end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery the code should be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // code goes here
});
```

Also, if you don’t wanna use jQuery you could say:

```
window.onload = function(){
   // code goes here
}
```

Or, finally, in the `<head><script>` tag define a function `foo()` and in the `<body>` tag give it onload attribute:

```
<body onload=foo()>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ok , I removed the () and I my js looks like this: $(document).ready(function(){ //code });. I load this script in the head but it does give me not the expected result as when I load it just before the body endtag

Comment: Did you try checking the console in your browser? Maybe there is some error preventing it to run correctly. Please do this then let me know.

Comment: Y2H you were right; there was an error and  I fixed it. Now it works fine!  Same result as if the script was at the end of document. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the function immediately after declaring it. This is because you are adding `()` to the end of your function. It should look more like this.

```
(function() {
// code js goes here
})
```

Here is more information on Immediately Invoked Function Expressions (IIFEs)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression